# How to jump back to current location after using key-binding `noremap <Leader>bA gg"*yG` without appending `<C-o><C-o>`?

Tags: key-bindings, normal-mode

I have created the following key-binding for copying all text in the buffer to the system clipboard:

`nnoremap <Leader>bA gg"*yG`

However, it moves the cursor, so I need to append `<C-o><C-o>` in order to jump back to the previous location.

How can I move back to the previous location without appending multiple `<C-o>` for a key-binding?

Comment: Instead of copy and pasting by moving, use the following ex command `:%y+`

Comment: Thank you. I only used the other approach, since I wasn't aware where to place the register `+`. I initially tried `:%y"+` etc. I created the mapping `noremap <Leader>by :<c-u>%y+<cr>`, do you like it, or could I improve it?

Comment: do **not** use the `"` on the ex command line, since it is being considered the comment char. Please also have a look at the help: `:h :y`. It doesn't mention to use the `"` in the ex commandline.

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out in a comment, perhaps the best way is to not move the cursor:

```
:%yank *
```

(or `+`, if you prefer that register). Can be shortened to `:%y*` if you prefer.

See [`:help :yank`](https://vimhelp.org/change.txt.html#%3Ayank) for details.

Comment: Thanks, you need to prefix your command by `:`